# Proguard 6 new "-android" option

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Proguard 6 is out since February and provides [some new features](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/proguard-60-released), among which the *-android* option

```
"A new option -android, to tune the optimizations for Android"
```

I would like to know more about this option, to understand what it really does in terms of optimization (& possibly obfuscation).

I search on guardsquare.com and Googled for it: I could only find a *dead* link about android on [this page](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/gradle). Here is the link:

> > **[android](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage.html#android)** <- dead link
>   Target the processed class files at Android.

**Where** can I find clear and detailed explanations about this new option?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/examples#androidapplication

Comment: @AshishJohn thanks for the link, but it does not provide explanations about the "-android" option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I search on guardsquare.com and Googled for it: I could only find a dead link

We can always look at source code!

First, I downloaded a snapshot 6.3.3 sources from [Sourceforge repository page](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/code/ci/96bcf75b766952f807729012c21383d3bf697e1f/tarball).

After unpacking:

```
grep -R android core/src/ | wc -l
27
```

Only 27 mentions of 'android'. Let's go over the list:

1. `maximum.inlined.code.length` is set to 32 for Android — 4 times as much as JVM  default
2. Additional inlining during some optimization stages (previously didn't work on Android, because it does not use preverification)
3. Replacing references to `FloatMath` with `Math` (not really that important of optimization...)
4. Resource charset set to UTF-8 (instead of system default charset)
5. Some legacy code for compatibility with Android Gradle plugin
6. ConfigurationLogger — as explained in documentation, "This class can be injected in applications to log information about reflection being used in the application code". The class supports Android-specific logging framework (aka `android.util.Log`)

5 and 6 aren't even related to the command-line `-android` option, — just some extra code, relevant for Android users.

Comment: Great! Just one question about "2." you wrote: "previously didn't work on Android, because it does not use preverification": I still have to use "-dontpreverify" in my Proguard file, right? as per the [documentation](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage), I think so